# Find all positive integers n such that $2^2 + 2^5+ 2^n$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Find all positive integers n such that $2^2 + 2^5 + 2^n$ is a perfect square. Explain your answer.

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  If $n=6$ we get $4+32+64=100$

Comment: Whoops, yep, misthought the binomial theorem. My reasoning is sound for $n$ even and $n\geq 10$. Then $\left(2^{n/2}+1\right)^2>2^{2}+2^5+2^n$. @lulu

Comment: Thank you @ lulu, @ Thomas Andrew

Comment: Providing us with your first steps is generally considered polite

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$2^n+36=m^2$$
$$2^n=(m-6)(m+6)$$
Both $m-6$ and $m+6$ must be powers of $2$ (and note that they differ by $12$). Can you continue?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve $36+2^n=k^2\iff2^n=k^2-6^2\iff2^n=(k-6)(k+6)$
So $\exists a,b \space such\space as\space k-6=2^a, k+6=2^b\space and \space a+b=n$. You make a small table : $2^0=1,2^1=2,2^2=4,2^3=8,2^4=16..$the only values for $2^a$ and $2^b$ with an offset of 12 are $2^a=16$ and $2^b=4$. So the only solution is $n=6$ indeed $16*4=28=2^6$.

Comment: The only solution is actually $n=6$.

Comment: oops I failed my addition